# How do I set a position of <h1> and <p> in jumbotron?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I would like to know how to set a position of h1 and p inside jumbotron. Lets say I would like to place my h1 in left corner of jumbotron and under h1 I would like to have p but with a little left-padding.

```css
.jumbotron {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: orange;
}
.jumbotron h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.jumbotron p {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1> Reserve your place </h1>
  <p>..before somebody will overtake you</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you!

```css
.jumbotron {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: orange;
}
.jumbotron h1 {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
.jumbotron p {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left:40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1> Reserve your place </h1>
        <p>..before somebody will overtake you</p>
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. It s working. But when I add to .jumbotron h1 also a padding-top:40px it is making my jumbotron widder and I dont want it.

Comment: you can reduce it as your wish.

Comment: I mean how do I place h1  higher or lower inside jumbotron (without changing the width of jumbotron)?

Comment: if you want to increase the space from top you can use padding-top and if u want to increase the font size you can use font-size

Answer (score 0):

You had some unnecessary positioning being set. There is absolutely no reason to give `h1` the `relative` positioning, and `absolute` to `p`.

Honestly, judging by the way you were using it I'd say you should do a little bit of learning and experimentation to fully understand the mechanics.

```css
.jumbotron {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: orange;
}
.jumbotron h1 {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.jumbotron p {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1> Reserve your place </h1>
  <p>..before somebody will overtake you</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you . Yes Im just beginner.....can you also help me when I add to .jumbotron h1 also a padding-top:40px  it is making my jumbotron widder and I dont want it. I want to just place my h1 more on top inside jumbotron.

Comment: Just lower or remove padding-top: 80px;

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this and its working my text is getting aligned to center, left or right.

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center container">
      <h1>This is demo</h1>
  </div>
```

Hope it will help.